# Help creating a workable design?

Tags: java, array

I received the following feedback for my code:

---

"I still do not see a design here that will work.

It is a very bad idea to have the big switch and loop at this point. All you need in your `main()` method is to create one object of each class and call the methods on them.

#### In class `Contact`:

- Every class needs a comment. The first thing you need to do is to write a comment for this class that starts with the words "one object of this class stores..." Once you are very clear on what one object of this class represents, the rest of the program (and my comments) will make sense. Until  you can write a comment like this, nothing will make sense.
- any method in this class has access to only one single contact. Therefore, your method `printContacts()` does not belong here.
- every method should do just one thing. Therefore, the method `printContacts()` — whatever class it is in — will *not* both read and print.
- I really think you need to throw away that method `printContacts()`. I don't believe that you will ever use that code. That is exactly why I asked you to leave all the method definitions blank for this deliverable.
- the welcome and the menu do not belong inside this class either. Methods in this class all must pertain *only* to exactly *one* contact

#### In class `ContactArray`:

I have no idea what this class is supposed to do, since you have no comment.

I still do not see a design here that will work for this project. What you need is three classes:

1. one class where one object of the class stores and manipulates the contact info for one person.
2. one class where one object of the class stores and manipulates the info for all of the people in the whole list. I do not see a class like this in your code, and that is why your design will not work.
3. one class with just a simple `main()` that just creates one object of each of the other two classes and calls all the methods on them. This is just for testing, to see that you know what each object represents and what you can do with each object.

The lesson here is to *never* try to code a class before you can write a comment that tells what one object of the class represents. Writing in Java is so much harder than writing in English, if you can't write it in English, you will never be able to write it in code.

The lack of comments for each class tells me that it was not reviewed carefully, quietly and independently by each team member. All of you have been working with the program guidelines all quarter, and so all of you should have caught this omission.

Please take your time and come up with a design that contains exactly three classes, as I described above. No menu, no user input, no code inside the `{ }` of the method definitions (except `main()`). *No file I/O*!

We are just trying to get a workable design here, struggling with the compiler is a time drain."

---

This is my code.

#### CONTACTLIST.JAVA

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    reader.useDelimiter("\n");

    ContactRunner runner;
    runner = new ContactRunner(reader);
    runner.run();
}

}
```

#### CONTACT.JAVA

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Contact {
private String lastname, firstname, address, city, zip, email, phone,
        notes;

public Contact(String lastnamename, String firstname, String address,
        String city, String zip, String email, String phone, String notes,
        String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.notes = notes;
}

public Contact() {

}

// overrides the default Object method
public String toString() {
    return lastname + ", " + firstname + ", " + address + ", " + city
            + ", " + zip + ", " + email + ", " + phone + ", " + notes;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for lastname to "s".
 */
void setLastName(String s) {
    lastname = s;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of lastname.
 */
String getLastName() {
    return lastname;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for firstname to "a".
 */
void setFirstName(String a) {
    firstname = a;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of firstname.
 */
String getFirstName() {
    return firstname;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for address to "b".
 */
void setHouseAddress(String b) {
    address = b;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of address.
 */
String getHouseAdress() {
    return address;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for city to "c".
 */
void setCity(String c) {
    city = c;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of city.
 */
String getCity() {
    return city;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for zip to "d".
 */
void setZip(String d) {
    zip = d;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of zip.
 */
String getZip() {
    return zip;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for phone to "e".
 */
void setPhone(String e) {
    phone = e;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of phone.
 */
String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for email to "f".
 */
void setEmail(String f) {
    email = f;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of email.
 */
String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

/*
 * Sets the value for notes to "g".
 */
void setNotes(String g) {
    notes = g;
}

/*
 * Returns the value of notes.
 */
String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

void welcome() {
    // Welcomes the user to the program for the first time.
    System.out.println("\nYou are in the Contact List DB. "
            + "What would you like to do? \n");

}

void menu() {
    // Prints out user menu written by Daniela.
    System.out.println("1. Enter a new person" + "\n"
            + "2. Print the contact list" + "\n"
            + "3. Retrieve a person's information by last name" + "\n"
            + "4. Retrieve a person's information by email address" + "\n"
            + "5. Retrieve all people who live in a given zip code" + "\n"
            + "6. Exit");

}

void printContacts() {
    // Read from file, print to console. by Damani Brown & Seth
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    int counter = 0;
    String line = null;

    // Location of file to read
    File file = new File("contactlist.csv");

    // Sort contacts and print to console
    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        // Before printing, add each line to a sorted set. by Seth
        // Copeland
        Set<String> lines = new TreeSet<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            lines.add(line);
            counter++;

        }

        // Print sorted contacts to console.
        for (String fileLine : lines) {
            String outlook = fileLine.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                    + fileLine.substring(1);
            System.out.println(outlook);

        }
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Sort contacts code. by Seth Copeland

        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    System.out.println("\n" + counter + " contacts in records.\n");

}

}
```

#### CONTACTARRAY.JAVA

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactArray {
private static Scanner reader;

public static void getContact() {
    reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    reader.useDelimiter("\n");
    /**
     * Array list created by Daniela Villalobos, used to create running list
     * of object contacts with lastname, firstname, address, city, zip,
     * phone, email, and notes
     */
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Contact contact;
    contact = new Contact();
    /**
     * Gets users contact information and adds the contact as a string in
     * our contact arraylist. - written by Daniela Vallalobos.
     */
    /**
     * Gets users contact information and adds the contact as a string in
     * our contact arraylist. - written by Daniela Vallalobos.
     */
    System.out.println("\nEnter Contact Last Name:");
    String lastname = reader.next();
    if (lastname == null) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry.\n");

    }

    else {
        contact.setLastName(lastname);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Contact First Name: ");
    contact.setFirstName(reader.next().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enter Contact Street Address: ");
    contact.setHouseAddress(reader.next().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enter Contact City: ");
    contact.setCity(reader.next().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enter Contact Zip Code: ");
    contact.setZip(reader.next().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enter Contact Email: ");
    contact.setEmail(reader.next().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enter Contact Phone Number: ");
    contact.setPhone(reader.next().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Enter Contact Notes: ");
    contact.setNotes(reader.next().toLowerCase());

    contacts.add(contact);

    /**
     * Writes contact information from user to file written by Damani Brown
     */
    FileOperations.write();
    Contact c = contact;
    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
            "contactlist.csv", true))) {
        output.printf("%s\r\n", c);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    System.out.println("Your contact has been saved.\n");

}

}
```

**CONTACTRUNNER.JAVA**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactRunner {
private Scanner reader;

public ContactRunner(Scanner reader) {
    this.run();
}

public void run() {
    Contact contact;
    contact = new Contact();
    int action = 0;

    contact.welcome();

    /**
     * While loop created to bring up user's choices - loop written by
     * Daniela Villalobos
     */
    while (action != 6) {

        contact.menu();
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        reader.useDelimiter("\n");
        action = reader.nextInt();
        /*
         * DV - if statement permits only actions 1-6 to execute a case
         */

        if (action <= 0 || action > 6) {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. ");

        }
        /**
         * Switch statement written by Daniela Villalobos
         */
        switch (action) {

        case 1: {

            /**
             * Gets users contact information and adds the contact as a
             * string in our contact arraylist. - written by Daniela
             * Vallalobos.
             */
            ContactArray.getContact();
            break;
        }

        /**
         * Prints out all records from file in alphabetical order
         */
        case 2: {
            contact.printContacts();
            /**
             * Reads contacts from file, sorts and prints them to console.
             */
            break;
        }

        /**
         * Ask's user to search for a lastname. Matches user input to record
         * of contacts, and prints out matching contact. - Coded by Seth &
         * Damani
         */
        case 3: {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the last" + "name to search for: ");
            /**
             * Gets the searchterm from the user and Matches user input to
             * existing contact records.
             */
            FileOperations.match();
            break;
        }

        /**
         * Ask's user to search for a email. Matches user input to record of
         * contacts, and prints out matching contact. - Coded by Seth &
         * Damani
         */
        case 4: {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the email "
                    + "address to search for: ");
            /**
             * Gets the searchterm from the user and Matches user input to
             * existing contact records.
             */
            FileOperations.match();
            break;
        }

        /**
         * Ask's user to search for a zipcode. Matches user input to record
         * of contacts, and prints out matching contact. - Coded by Seth &
         * Damani
         */
        case 5: {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the Zipcode " + "to search for: ");
            /**
             * Gets the searchterm from the user and Matches user input to
             * existing contact records.
             */
            FileOperations.match();
            break;
        }
        case 6: {
            System.out.println("\nNow quitting application...");
            System.exit(action);

        }
        }

    }
}
}
```

#### FILEOPERATIONS.JAVA

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileOperations {

private static Scanner reader;

public static void write() {
    // Creates and writes to file
    try {

        File file = new File("contactlist.csv");

        // If file doesn't exists, then create it.
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

static void match() {
    // Matches user input to existing contact records.
    try {

        // Open the file as a buffered reader
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "contactlist.csv"));

        // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our
        // current line.
        int linecount = 0;
        String line;
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchterm = reader.next();
        // Let the user know what we are searching for
        System.out.println("\nSearching for " + searchterm + " in file...");
        // Loop through each line, putting the line into our line
        // variable.
        boolean noMatches = true;
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            // Increment the count and find the index of the word.
            linecount++;
            int indexfound = line.indexOf(searchterm);

            // If greater than -1, means we found a match.
            if (indexfound > -1) {
                System.out.println("\nContact was FOUND\n" + "\nContact "
                        + linecount + ": " + line);
                noMatches = false;
            }

        }

        // Close the file after done searching
        bf.close();
        if (noMatches) {
            System.out.println("\nNO MATCH FOUND.\n");
        }
    }

    // Catches any exception errors
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
    }

}

}
```

First she says we don't have enough classes and our `main` was too long. Suggested moving our `main` and our array list into different classes. We did that, and she's still says it's not a workable design. Program seem to run fine to me, how is it not workable? There is just no pleasing her. Can anyone translate her feedback into English so a beginner coder can understand. This is my 3rd time resubmitting this design document. We are already suppose to be starting the next step, but she won't let us continue until we have a "Workable" design. (yet program runs fine). So now I have to pretty much erase my whole code (which I worked countless days and nights on) and make a "workable" design/skeleton with pretty much no code that pleases her. Any help so that I can move forward would simply be AMAZING.

Regards,

Comment: Explaining what the code is supposed to be doing would be nice. A bit hard to review without any context. Also, could you perhaps give the question a real title?

Comment: The code is suppose to create a contact list where a user can add contacts, print all contacts to console, search a contact by last name, search a contact by email, and search a contact by zipcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, then you were tasked to *design* not to *implement* such a system. So you were asked to specify the interface, or API.

### Example in English:

#### Class Contact:

represents a contact. Has getters/setters for name, email, etc.

#### Class AddressBook:

a collection where contacts can be `add`ed and `remove`d. Provides `searchFoo` methods that take a string and returns a List of contacts whose `foo` field contains that string as substring (where `foo` is name, email, etc).

(If you know SQL, the interface of `AddressBook` would mirror `INSERT foo`, `DELETE foo` and `SELECT foo WHERE bar` like actions)

The AB also has a method to write a representation itself to a Writer, or to load contacts from a Reader. A constructor that would initialize the AB from a file would be pretty nifty.

#### Class Shell:

provides a text interface to `AddressBook`. Has methods to display forms like

```
Contact createContactDialog();       // guide the user through creating a new contact
void changeContactDialog(Contact c); // change fields of existing contact
void displayContact(Contact c);      // just display the contact
void searchDialog();                 // start dialog to search the AB
```

Each Shell has fields `in` and `out` which are a Reader and Writer, and an `AddressBook ab`.

The Shell has a `run` method which will start the shell, and basically handles the rest of the control flow. (Internally, this would be a `while (true)` loop that prompts the user for some action, and then dispatches appropriate dialogs. The loop (an the `run` method) is left by a command like `exit`)

No other class will have user interface code!

(Especially your `FileOperations` class is bad: This class is just a collection of helper functions, and does not represent a useful entity in itself. Classes containing only `static` stuff are not object oriented. Compare OOP to procedural programming, like in C or Pascal or whatnot)

#### The main():

Here you create some `Contact`s, put them into an `AddressBook`, create a `Shell` with that, and let it `run`.

---

Now, you translate all that to Java (without specifying the implementation except for `main`), put pretty comments everywhere and are done.

Some hints for the actual implementation:

- Don't require the user to type numbers. Use meaningful full-text commands (like `new`, `update`, `search`), or at least mnemonic letters (`c` for create, `u` for update, `/` for search, like in Vim). You can easily compare given input via regular expression. Java is quite good with “Regexes”.
- Don't lowercase the data in your contacts. If you want to search for contacts case-insensitively, then you can lowercase the data for comparision. However, storing the changed data is a bug, as lowercasing changes the meaning of text.

Comment: Sir, this was in English! Congrats. I had no clue what she was saying. But you've cleared it up. Thanks. Although it's only suppose to be three classes. This should be enough to get me started.